# Show alert when subscribe ends

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm needing some help...

There are two endpoints.

- updateVariable (to update every variable modified, could be 2 or more).
- updateDocument (to update document, this happens once).

I need to update the document after to update all the variables available.
This is my code, and it works, but it's slow. It's waiting to finish to update one variable to go for the next. I know with a mergeMap I could update all the variables at the same time, but I don't know what is the best way to implement it.

```
  async onClickUpdateForm() {
    let variables = this.componenList.getForm;

    for await (let x of this.documentContent.variables) {
      var var_id: string = x._id;
      
      var category = variables.find((e) => e.category == x.category.name);
      
      // *THIS IS JUST ELEMENTS TO ADD IN THE OBJECT TO SEND*
      var element = category.parameters.find(
        (e: { name: any }) => e.name == x.name
      );

      if (!x.isAConditional) {
        var dataToSend = {
          isAConditional: x.isAConditional,
          name: element.name,
          label: element.label,
          description: x.description,
          type: element.type,
          values: element.values,
          html_content: x.html_content,
          position: x.position,
          quantity: x.quantity,
          placeholder: element.placeholder,
          isRequired: element.isRequired,
        };
      } else {
        var dataToSend = {
          isAConditional: x.isAConditional,
          name: x.name,
          label: x.label,
          description: x.description,
          type: x.type,
          values: x.values,
          html_content: x.html_content,
          position: x.position,
          quantity: x.quantity,
          isRequired: x.isRequired,
          placeholder: x.placeholder,
        };
      }

      // *UPDATING VARIABLE*
      await this._documentService
        .updateVariable(dataToSend, this.documentId, var_id)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .toPromise()
        .then((x) => {
          console.log(x);
        });
    }

    let dataToUpdate: any = {
      name: this.nameForm,
      description: this.descriptionForm,
      owner: this.userId,
      status_doc: 'EDIT_FORM',
    };

    // *UPDATING DOCUMENT*
    this._documentService
      .updateDocument(dataToUpdate, this.documentId)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((x) => {
        console.log(x);
        this._messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Updated',
          detail: 'The form was updated.',
        });
      });
  }
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it you have two independent observables sources. To process one and when that finishes process the other one, you can use `concat(obs1, obs2)`.

It would be something like this.

```
onClickUpdateForm() {
  let variables = this.componenList.getForm;
  let dataToUpdate: any = {
    name: this.nameForm,
    description: this.descriptionForm,
    owner: this.userId,
    status_doc: 'EDIT_FORM',
  };
  
  concat(
    from(this.documentContent.variables).pipe(
      mergeMap(x => {
        ... // <-- all your mapping
        return this._documentService.updateVariable(dataToSend, this.documentId, var_id)  
      });
    ),
    this._documentService.updateDocument(dataToUpdate, this.documentId)
  ).pipe(
    tap({
      complete: () => {
        this._messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Updated',
          detail: 'The form was updated.',
        });
      }
    })
  ).subscribe()
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Nice! There are many operators that I didn't know. I learned so much with your reply, thank you! But, I have several problems with your code, but I have the idea. Basically, "concat" is deprecated. I'm trying to use it with "concatWith" but It does not work. On the other hand, I think that mergeMap operator can't be combined with from operator, I can get something only using subscribe with from.
from(iterator).subscribe(x=>{})

Comment: The `concat()` function is not deprecated. The one deprecated is the `concat` pipeable operator ( `obs1.pipe(concat(obs2))` ) in favor as you said of `concatWith()`. So be sure you are importing it from 'rxjs' and not from 'rxjs/operators'. Regarding `mergeMap`, it can surely be used with `from` as a source. Just be sure you are returning an observable in its mapping function. // Btw I updated the answer since I forgot to link the `tap` cb to the `complete` notification.

Comment: I got it about `concat()` and `tap`. Regarding `mergeMap`, I can't use the elements on `from`.  The argument `x` in `mergeMap` contains every iteration of `this.documentContent.variable` right? (Remember that this variable just contains an array of objects). I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried a `console.log(x)` to see what I'm getting but nothing happens (any `console.log` is showed). Excuse me, I'm learning rxjs :D

Comment: Correct, in `x` you get each element of the array (same that you were getting in your `for...of`). Regarding the `console.log` not logging, without seeing the code I'm afraid I can't help you. Check that your concat syntax is correct and you're subscribing to it (`concat(obs1$, obs2$).subscribe()`). // btw you don't need to apologize ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Promise.all` in JS, that is waiting for all promises to be resolved. For example:

```js
async onClickUpdateForm() {
    let variables = this.componenList.getForm;

    // ---> Wait for all promises to be resolved
    await Promise.all(this.documentContent.variables.map((x) => {
      var var_id: string = x._id;
      
      // your logic here...

      // *UPDATING VARIABLE*
      return this._documentService
        .updateVariable(dataToSend, this.documentId, var_id)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .toPromise();
    }));

    let dataToUpdate: any = {
      name: this.nameForm,
      description: this.descriptionForm,
      owner: this.userId,
      status_doc: 'EDIT_FORM',
    };

    // *UPDATING DOCUMENT*
    this._documentService
      .updateDocument(dataToUpdate, this.documentId)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((x) => {
        console.log(x);
        this._messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Updated',
          detail: 'The form was updated.',
        });
      });
  }
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: It'll be waiting also for every request and the process will be slow.

Comment: `Promise.all` will execute all promises in parallel, and will resolve when the last one is done. So your script will be faster.

Comment: I got it. But I'm trying to join in rxjs world. I think that the solution could be using rxjs operators.